# r2 results from envfit in vegan package

Tags: r, vegan

What does the r2 in the envfit results mean?

I understand that the values provided with respect to the axes (PCA, NMDS etc) are the correlation coefficients and the pvalue is the test of significance. But I do not understand what does the r2 stand for?

If it is the usual R aquare that is seen in a regression approach, then where are the degrees of fit in envfit?

Comment: Not really a coding question. Questions about interpretation should go to package authors or forums devoted to the underlying theory, perhaps stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r2` stands for the squared correlation coefficient. It is the correlation of the environmental (external) variable and the ordination scores projected onto the arrow (not the axes). What would you do with the degrees of freedom?